# Unable to create lambda function using cloud formation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Error: Properties validation failed for resource autoTaggingLambda with message: #/Role: expected type: String, found: JSONArray

Code below:

```
Resources:
autoTaggingLambda:
    
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: 
            "import json
             import boto3
             import logging
             import time
             from datetime import date"
```

Comment: You have to provide full code. Your current template is not even valid, and will never run.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach in-line multiline `python` script in your CloudFormation template using the `|` Operator

```yaml
  autoTaggingLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      .
      .
      .
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import boto3
          import json
          ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
          def get_instance_ids():
          .
          .
          .
```

You can check the official docs for a sample implementation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html